# Compare different time zone date in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to compare dates from different time zone?

for e.g.

```
x = "2013-12-02T10:10:17-0400" // (timezone EST)
```

and compare this date to current date

```
var d = new Date(); // timezone(PST)
```

check  x < d ?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? i.e. what is the output you want to see? Also, why is this question tagged "jQuery" and "performance" if it is about how to manipulate JavaScript date objects?

Comment: 1. it has nothing to do with jQuery nor `performance`. 2. what do you want to compare?

Comment: Better convert them to milliseconds and compare, that will solve the problem.  there is nothing to do with timezone

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to dealing with dates and times in JavaScript, I usually use **Moment.js** which is a library exactly for this purpose.

Its URL is http://momentjs.com/

Then you can simply parse the given string with this line:

```
// Parse the given datetime
var mydate = moment("2013-12-02T10:10:17-0400");
```

And you can also compare two different `moment` values:

```
// Compare given datetime with the current datetime
if (moment("2013-12-02T10:10:17-0400") > moment()) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you can just convert it to a regular JavaScript `Date` object:

```
// Parse given datetime and convert to Date object
var mydate = moment("2013-12-02T10:10:17-0400").toDate();
// Compare to current datetime
if (mydate > (new Date())) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that the unary `+` operator also works with `moment` objects just as you would expect. So `+moment()` outputs the same as `+(new Date())`.

It's also very well documented, the [Moment.js docs page](http://momentjs.com/docs/) has a ton of examples and useful info about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Better convert any of the dates to a common timezone(better to have UTC)
2. Now convert the datetime to milliseconds
3. Compare the milliseconds

Hope you understand

Comment: I think OP is going to need more hep than that... I can just tell

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript library to manipulate dates in different time zones: https://github.com/mde/timezone-js

It uses the TZ database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database